# Ambassador GRPC healthcheck

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, grpc, aws-application-load-balancer, ambassador

We have ambassador(on v1.2.2) exposed via AWS ALB. We have enabled GRPC as a backend protocol where ALB expects GRPC status code for health check on target ambassador pods.
Does ambassador has GRPC health check endpoint? If so on which port?